# comma separated value in php adding space and small square

Tags: php

I have a text area in a form im writing pasting the comma separated value in the text area

like

```
1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10

11,12,13,14,15
```

when i submit from its creating a csv file but the csv file in the row 1 contains header

its appending the 1 st row with the first row value of the comma separated value

i get like this ,iget the small square and the first row of comma separated value is

appended to the header

```
id, grpname, grpid,code,name1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10

11,12,13,14,15
```

heres the code

```
$csvdata = $_REQUEST['csvdata'];
$arr     = explode(",", $csvdata);
$fname   = 'file.csv';

$fp = fopen($fname, 'w');

$heading_row = array('id', 'grpname', 'grpid', 'code', 'name');
fputcsv($fp, $heading_row);

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $v = trim($val);
    $v .= ',';

    fwrite($fp, $v, strlen($v)) || die("not written");

}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. A code block is inserted by indenting 4 spaces before any line of code. I've formatted the code for you this time, but please format it properly next time. For further help, see the [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Being nosy..... When you're adding the header, you're using fputcsv, but when you're writing the data, you're using fwrite. Is there a reason why you're not using the same function in both places?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$csvdata = $_REQUEST['csvdata'];
$arr     = explode(",", $csvdata);
$fname   = 'file.csv';

$fp = fopen($fname, 'w');

$heading_row = array('id', 'grpname', 'grpid', 'code', 'name');
fputcsv($fp, $heading_row);

foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $v = "\n";
    $v.= trim($val);
    $v.= ',';

    fwrite($fp, $v, strlen($v)) || die("not written");

}
fclose($fp);
```

Please next time, take your time to write your post. It was very messy. Thanks to @Truth for making readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
```

I think this link will be helpful
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileappend.php